# Update UIButton title and select the action accordingly using RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I am new to `RxSwift`, so I wonder If it is possible to update `UIButton` title and select the action accordingly using `RxSwift`.

Say, I have a custom `UIButton` inside my `UITableViewCell` which I intend it to trigger a set of custom actions when the user taps, (e.g: like or dislike image or post or whatever...)

So, is that possible, for instance, to set the custom title, image, and action of a `UIButton` accordingly, and update the UI..

For more explanation of the point, say, I have two actions user can interact with the button: `func imageDisliked()` and `imageLiked()`, So when the Image is disliked, I want the button to set its title "imageDisliked" and its icon "dislikeIcon" and vice versa..

is that possible with `RxSwift`?

Comment: Of course it's possible. What is the trigger that causes the effect? Rx is all about cause and effect. You have told us what you want the effect to be, what's the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Rx is all about cause and effect. Some things cause events to happen and some things listen for an event and do something as a result.

A button tap `myButton.rx.tap` emits events, it's a cause. A button's title `myButton.rx.title(for: .normal)` is an effect. So is its image `myButton.rx.image(for: .normal)`.

As for your `imageLiked()` and `imageDisliked()`, at this point they sound like effects, but you haven't outlined the causes properly yet.

So the answer to your question is, yes it is possible to update a UIButton. You just need to outline what effects you want, and for each effect you need to outline the cause or causes.